# How to update a C++ string within a function?

Tags: c++, string, arduino, arduino-uno

Suppose I want to write a C++ function foo() that updates the value of an input string. How do I do it? The code should probably look something like I have below but I don't know how to properly pass the string such that it is updated by the function.

```
void foo(String x) // Not sure if I should put an & or * before x
{
    x += " Goodbye";
}

void main()
{
    String x = "Hello World";
    cout << "x = " << x << endl;
    foo(x);  // Not sure if I should pass a pointer to x,
             // a reference to x or what?

    cout << "After foo (), x = " << x << endl;
}
```

(FYI, I'm writing this for an Arduino processor)

Answer (score 4):

Pass by reference:

```
void foo(String& x)
{
    x += " Goodbye";
}
```

The `&` means the parameter is a reference to the `String` outside the function rather than a copy.

Answer (score 1):

In order to update the string from within the function, you need to pass a reference to the string as input:

```
void foo(String& x) 
{
    x += " Goodbye";
}
```

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value) explains the difference between pass-by-reference and pass-by-value.

Regarding your confusion between using `&` or `*` in the function signature, you can either

1. use `&` as described above OR
2. you could define foo as `void foo(String *x)`. However, in this case, when you call `foo`, you would need to call it as `foo(&x);`.

In the first case, you're passing the input as a reference variable while in the second case, you're passing it in as a pointer variable. The differences between them are explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in).

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of the following methods: -

1. void foo(String *x) in function header and foo(&x); in main().

or,

2. void foo(String &x) in function header and foo(x); in main().